# How do I parse variables from ajax to a controller and return a bool

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to parse 2 strings (Just testing with one atm( consiting of a date from a datepicker and hour and minute from 2 textfields. But I cant figure out how to parse data from my ajax call to the method I call, I know its called as I checked with a breakpoint, but its parameter is just null.

My ajax:

```
$('.datein').change(function () {
    alert("datein changed");
    //send servervalidering ajax
    var result = false;
    $.ajax({ url: "Resource/isDateValid/",
            data: ($('#resource_datein').val() + "-" + $('#resource_hourin').val() + "-" + $('#resource_minutein').val()),
        type: "POST",
        sucess: ajaxsuccess(result)
    }
    );
});
```

My methodcall on success

```
function ajaxsuccess(result) {
    alert("ajax lykkes!" + result);
}
```

And the controller method which is part of public class ResourceController : DataTablesController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool isDateValid(string dateIn)
    {

        return true;
    }
```

string dateIn just returns null if I set a date

Comment: You have a typo there: `sucess: ajaxsuccess(result)` should be `success: ajaxsuccess(result)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the parameter is still null, also it seems like the alert is displayed before it gets into the action method, it shouldnt launch the popup before it have the result from the action method :/

Comment: have to checked in firebug are you getting a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
//js

var data = $("myform").serialize(); //Might be serializeArray() not on dev machine sorry

$.post("Resource/isDateValid/", data, function(data){
   alert(data.Success);
}, "json");
```

Controller (assuming Resource is a class because of the underscore in the ids...)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult(Resource resource) //or (DateTime resource_datein, int resource_hourin)
{
    bool success = true;

    //Do something with posted data

    return Json(new { Success = success});
}
```

EDIT (re comment)

take the () off the AjaxSuccess function call in the $.post

```
$('.datein').change(function () {
            //send servervalidering ajax
            var data = $(".datein").serialize();
            $.post("Resource/isDateValid", data, ajaxsuccess, "text");
        });
```

with

```
function ajaxsuccess(data)
{
   alert(data.Success); // in your case alert(data); because it's "text"?
}
```

also because you are not serializing the entire form your data should be:

```
var data = {dateIn : $(".datein").val()};
```

Comment: The isDataValid still just recieves null values http://pastebin.com/rZ59Ct4R and the action is still not called until after the alert is fired

Comment: take the () off the AjaxSuccess function call in the $.post